# Нужны ли запятые в этом обороте?

Tags: пунктуация

Уплотнение корпуса 4 выполнено из (...) и препятствует выходу наружу среды, в случае механического повреждения основного уплотнения, и проникновению атмосферы снаружи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оборот имеет значение уточнения, и его лучше обособить.

В этом случае лучше просматриваются однородные члены "препятствует выходу наружу среды и проникновению атмосферы снаружи".